# open second content editor that points to different database

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible to open second content editor, in sitecore desktop, that points to different database?

I want to edit content from core and master database without need to switch between databases.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. [Check out this blog post](http://blog.istern.dk/2013/10/31/adding-two-usefull-shortcuts-to-the-sitecore-startmenu/).